# OData in AngularJS returns empty Array

Tags: angularjs, odata

coming from this working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/h22f7596/ , I am trying to display the content of a json-file from my own OData Service in AngularJS.

HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="Adressen in results">
       {{Adressen.Street}}

        <strong style="float:right">
            {{Adressen.PLZ}}
        </strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myModule = angular.module("MyModule",['ODataResources']);
myModule.controller("MyController",function($scope,$odataresource){
$scope.results = 

$odataresource("https://xsgeos0015309874trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/s0015309874trial/xsgeo/geotabelle/geoDB/GeotabelleODataService.xsodata/Adressen",  [],
                {
                  odata:{

                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    transformResponse: function (data) {
                    return angular.fromJson(data).value;
                    }
                  } 

                })
                .odata()


                .format("json")
                .filter("Street", "Kölner Straße")
                .filter("Hausnummer", "22")
                .take(5)
                .query();


                });
```

I dont know why no data is displayed, because in Chromes console, I can see that the OData request is transferred succesfully, but it is not displayed in my controller and when I look at console.log($scope.results) it shows me an empty array.

Please take a look at my example and tell me what I did wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/h22f7596/123/

Thank you in advance.

/edit: Updated Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were accessing the data wrong. If you would have printed the entire object you would have seen:

```
Object: {
    d: {
        results: {
            ....    
        }
    }
}
```

Change your return to:

```
return angular.fromJson(data).d.results
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h22f7596/124/

Comment: Is there a way to set the filters in the $odataresource dynamically?